# Unity3d OnTriggerEnter, animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my character to play an animation when pressing a key when it enters the trigger, but I couldn't figure it out. Can you help? Here is my code.

```
public Text text;
public Animator anim;

public void Start()
{
    text.enabled = false;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

public void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    text.enabled = true;
}

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        anim.Play("DoorOpen");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) takes a parameter of type `Collider` .. otherwise it is never called by Unity.

Then either set a `bool` flag to `true` and reset it to `false` in [`OnTriggerExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) - you could e.g. use the `text.enabled` which you are setting anyway

public Text text;
public Animator anim;

```
private void Start()
{
    text.enabled = false;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (text.enabled && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        anim.Play("DoorOpen");
    } 
}

private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = false;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = true;
}
```

or instead of poll checking it in `Update` you can rather directly use [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) which is repeatedly called as long as you are hitting the trigger

```
public Text text;
public Animator anim;

private void Start()
{
    text.enabled = false;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        anim.Play("DoorOpen");
    } 
}

private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = false;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = true;
}
```